# Cannot start mysql server

Tags: mysql, debian

I'm tring to run a website from my server, so I installed php, apache and mysql.

I'm having problems with mysql.  After installation, it failed to restart.

This is the output:

```
root@ns213360:/etc/mysql# /etc/init.d/mysql start ; tail -n 50 /var/log/syslog
[FAIL] Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
Apr  3 09:27:22 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:27:22 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
Apr  3 09:27:22 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:27:22 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
Apr  3 09:27:22 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:27:22 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
Apr  3 09:27:22 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:27:22 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
Apr  3 09:27:22 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:27:22  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
Apr  3 09:27:23 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:27:23 InnoDB: 5.5.35 started; log sequence number 1595685
Apr  3 09:27:23 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:27:23 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'default-character-set=utf8'
Apr  3 09:27:23 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:27:23 [ERROR] Aborting
Apr  3 09:27:23 ns213360 mysqld:
Apr  3 09:27:23 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:27:23  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Apr  3 09:27:24 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:27:24  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595685
Apr  3 09:27:24 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:27:24 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Arrêt du serveur terminé
Apr  3 09:27:24 ns213360 mysqld:
Apr  3 09:27:24 ns213360 mysqld_safe: mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
Apr  3 09:27:36 ns213360 /etc/init.d/mysql[24960]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
Apr  3 09:27:36 ns213360 /etc/init.d/mysql[24960]: #007/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
Apr  3 09:27:36 ns213360 /etc/init.d/mysql[24960]: error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Apr  3 09:27:36 ns213360 /etc/init.d/mysql[24960]: Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
Apr  3 09:27:36 ns213360 /etc/init.d/mysql[24960]:
Apr  3 09:28:01 ns213360 /USR/SBIN/CRON[24980]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 40 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
Apr  3 09:29:01 ns213360 /USR/SBIN/CRON[25025]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 40 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
Apr  3 09:29:19 ns213360 mysqld_safe: Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Apr  3 09:29:19 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:29:19 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
Apr  3 09:29:19 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:29:19 [Warning] The syntax '--log-slow-queries' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--slow-query-log'/'--slow-query-log-file' instead.
Apr  3 09:29:19 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:29:19 [ERROR] An old style --language value with language specific part detected: /usr/share/mysql/french/
Apr  3 09:29:19 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:29:19 [ERROR] Use --lc-messages-dir without language specific part instead.
Apr  3 09:29:19 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:29:19 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
Apr  3 09:29:19 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:29:19 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
Apr  3 09:29:19 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:29:19 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
Apr  3 09:29:19 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:29:19 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
Apr  3 09:29:19 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:29:19 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
Apr  3 09:29:19 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:29:19 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
Apr  3 09:29:19 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:29:19 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
Apr  3 09:29:19 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:29:19 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
Apr  3 09:29:19 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:29:19 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
Apr  3 09:29:19 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:29:19  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
Apr  3 09:29:20 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:29:20 InnoDB: 5.5.35 started; log sequence number 1595685
Apr  3 09:29:20 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:29:20 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'default-character-set=utf8'
Apr  3 09:29:20 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:29:20 [ERROR] Aborting
Apr  3 09:29:20 ns213360 mysqld:
Apr  3 09:29:20 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:29:20  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Apr  3 09:29:21 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:29:21  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595685
Apr  3 09:29:21 ns213360 mysqld: 140403  9:29:21 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Arrêt du serveur terminé
Apr  3 09:29:21 ns213360 mysqld:
Apr  3 09:29:21 ns213360 mysqld_safe: mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
Apr  3 09:29:33 ns213360 /etc/init.d/mysql[25685]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
Apr  3 09:29:33 ns213360 /etc/init.d/mysql[25685]: #007/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
Apr  3 09:29:33 ns213360 /etc/init.d/mysql[25685]: error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Apr  3 09:29:33 ns213360 /etc/init.d/mysql[25685]: Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
Apr  3 09:29:33 ns213360 /etc/init.d/mysql[25685]:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the log, there is an error with a variable : `unknown variable 'default-character-set=utf8'`

`default-character-set` is a variable used for the client and not for the server.

I suspect that in your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file, there is a line

> default-character-set=utf8

in the section `[mysqld]` instead of the section `[mysql]` or `[client]`.

If you want to force your server to run with the UTF8 character set by default, in the `my.cnf` file you have to put

> character-set-server = utf8

in the section `[mysqld]`.

So your `my.cnf` file should looks like this:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
```

the two last lines are there to enforce the use of the UTF8 'case insensitive' collation together with the UTF8 character set.

Once your MySQL will be start up, you can verify that UTF8 is used by issuing the following command at the Mysql prompt :

```
mysql> show variables like 'char%';
```

giving a result like this one (for my own server - yours can be different) :

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score -1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf8-in-my-cnf), you need to change the line

```
default-character-set=uf8
```

in the file /etc/my.cnf to:

```
character-set-system=utf8
```

and try again to start the server.

Comment: Why the downvotes? It is the same answer as the accepted one, only shorter.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2485758